# Why did the Byzantine military strength decline?

Tags: byzantine-empire, army

At the start and peak of the glory of the Byzantine Empire, it had more than **350,000 well-trained soldiers** at the time of Justinian I. But the size of the army declined heavily over the period from 540-565 AD, so the army was down to only **a hundred thousand soldiers**.

This pattern continues for the next 900 years until the Fall of Constantinople, where the Byzantines only had 7,000 men to defend the city, of which 2,000 were mercenaries. They were hopelessly outnumbered by 80,000-120,000 Ottomans and the city fell.

Here are some ideas I have about this:

- **The Fourth Crusade** ended in the sack of the city of Constantinople, draining many resources and the royal treasury of the Byzantine Empire. The Crusaders did this to repay some debts.
- **Many enemy empires.** The Byzantine Empire was attacked by the Crusaders, the Umayyad Caliphate, the Abbasid Empire, and Persia. It lost key areas to recruit more soldiers when Asia Minor was lost to the Muslims.
- **Extensive loss of territory.** Over the course of time, the Byzantine Empire lost vast expanses of territory, notably Syria and Egypt, which were its main powerhouses of wealth.

[image: Decline of army]

Comment: Justinian I ruled from 527 to 565, so your first paragraph does not really seem to mske sense. It is also not consistent with your diagram, which has no more than 150 000 soldiers during Justinian's reign (not 350 000)

Comment: Doesn't [Decline of the Byzantine Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decline_of_the_Byzantine_Empire) help? If not, please explain why. Also, if you didn't make the graph yourself, you need to source it (and if you did make it, where did the data come from?).

Comment: Can you be more specific? You want an explanation for a period of +1000 years. Each period in that time frame has different reasons.

Comment: Also, if you meant Theodosius I and not Justinian I, the big downfall in numbers is probably due to the split of western and eastern roman empire.

Comment: In a phrase: ***Cultural Collapse***. The will to finance and manage a military capable of defense simply evaporated. Look around you: the same is plaguing nearly every NATO member today.

Comment: I worked up a graph with this data plotted alongside population and land area, but the Q got closed before I would put it in an answer. I've [dropped it in our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1560/the-time-machine) for safekeeping, if anyone wants to look at it.